# Accessing turnContext from Bot Composer generated code

Tags: c#, logging, botframework

I have created a chat bot using Bot Framework Composer, and I’m trying to get the plain text of the different conversation turns, for logging purposes.

I have found this [resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-v4-storage?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp), where it explains how to do it, but it only applies for the Microsoft Bot Framework v4 sdk.

However, since the code generated by Framework Composer and Bot Framework SDK is different I don’t know how to access the Activity object or the turnContext info.

Is there any way to access this info from the code generated by Bot Framework Composer?

I have tried printing from SkillController.cs and BotController.cs. However, the Activity object that might contain the turnContext is empty.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for [telemetry for Composer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/composer/how-to-capture-telemetry?tabs=v2x)? Or is there a reason you do not want to use the built-in client?

Answer (score 1):

Follow the following steps:-

1.Ask for input text and than store it using "Set a property".
[image: Manage properties>>Set a property]

2.If you want you can give different variable names each time whenever you want to store user response.
[image: Add variable name]

3.You can use the variable name to access the response.
[image]

Here is the output:-
[image: Enter what you want>>Help me>>User response:-Help me]

And you can also merge it in a loop for storing multiple response.

Answer (score 0):

Write the custom middleware to access turn context object
here the video steps how to create custom middleware using [bot composer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AfQ9zm7K0HI)